# 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable when range is wider than content

Tags: http, http-headers, vite, geotiff, http-content-range

I get an Error 416 Range Not Satisfiable response when I make an http request with a byte-range of 0-65536. The byte length of the file requested is only 3356.

Reading the spec on `byte-range`, it sounds like requesting a range that extends beyond the length of the file is okay, and in this case I would expect the entire file to be fetched. https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#byte.ranges

> A client can limit the number of bytes requested without knowing the size of the selected representation. If the last-pos value is absent, or if the value is greater than or equal to the current length of the representation data, the byte range is interpreted as the remainder of the representation (i.e., the server replaces the value of last-pos with a value that is one less than the current length of the selected representation).

**Am I misreading the spec or is this request truly unsatisfiable?** I prefer if my client does not need to know the size of the file before making the request; they could vary widely in size. The request is successful if I limit the byte-range to <= the length of the file.

The file requested is a cloud-optimized-geotiff. It is being served by a vite dev server. And the request is made using `OpenLayers` and `geotiff.js`.

Here are the DevTools details of the request and response:

```
General
---------
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/scenarios/1/1_parcel_fill.tif
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 416 Range Not Satisfiable
Remote Address: [::1]:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
--------------------
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Range: bytes */3356
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2022 21:38:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

Request Headers
-------------------
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: identity
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:3000
Pragma: no-cache
Range: bytes=0-65536
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: I believe your interpretation is correct, and this particular server does not follow the spec. Can you name it? As an example, Apache responds to `Range: bytes=0-9999999` with a 206 and `Content-Range: bytes 0-1630/1631`.

Comment: Oh interesting, thanks @Joe. Right now this is only running in a vite dev server. Which I suppose is probably a simple http server provided by nodejs. Good to know that the server is where to look for the solution.

Comment: I confirmed that this same request returns a 206 when I host the data on a different server (S3 bucket). So this does seem like a deficiency in the vite/node http server.

Comment: Had the same problem: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/13519